# Puppeteer: Scraping multiple Url

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, web-scraping, puppeteer

Using Node.js, I'm scraping a few different websites.
I can't retrieve all the information I need on all the pages
I have little knowledge of Puppeteer, yet I tried to do it, watch lots of tutorials/forums
Can you help me?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

let queue = [
  'https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre/',
  'https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre/?p=1',
  'https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre/?p=2',
  'https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre/?p=3',
]

async function scrapeData() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  let url
  while(url = queue.shift()){
    await page.goto(url)
  }

  // Naviguer vers la page cible
 // await page.goto('https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre/');

  // Attendre que les éléments contenant les données des produits soient chargés sur la page
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__price');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__img');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__description');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__availability');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__brand');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__sku');

  // Extraire les données des produits en utilisant une fonction de la page
  const productsData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const priceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__price');
    const imageElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__img');
    const titleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__description');
    const stockElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__availability');
    const brandElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__brand');
    const referenceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__sku');

    const products = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < priceElements.length; i++) {
      const price = priceElements[i].textContent;
      const imageUrl = imageElements[i].getAttribute('src');
      const title = titleElements[i].textContent;
      const instock = stockElements[i].textContent;
      const brand = brandElements[i].textContent;
      const reference = referenceElements[i].textContent;

      products.push({ price, imageUrl, title, instock, brand, reference });
    }

    return products;
  });

  // Fermer le navigateur
  await browser.close();

  return productsData;
}
[1,2,3].map(() => scrapeData())

// Fonction pour enregistrer les données dans MongoDB
async function saveDataToMongoDB(data) {
  const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'; // Changez cette URL en fonction de votre configuration MongoDB
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connecté à MongoDB');

    const database = client.db('scraped_data');
    const collection = database.collection('testing');

    // Supprimer les données existantes dans la collection
    await collection.deleteMany({});

    // Insérer les données dans la collection
    await collection.insertMany(data);

    console.log('Données enregistrées avec succès dans MongoDB');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Une erreur est survenue lors de la connexion ou de l\'enregistrement dans MongoDB:', error);
  } finally {
    // Fermer la connexion MongoDB
    await client.close();
  }
}

// Appeler la fonction de scraping, enregistrer les données dans MongoDB et afficher les données des produits
scrapeData()
  .then((data) => {
    saveDataToMongoDB(data);
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error('Une erreur est survenue lors du scraping:', error));
```

I have tried almost everything and would like to retrieve information such as price, product title, part number, and image URL, and store everything on a database (MongoDB).

Edit :
it's fine on all pages, but it doesn't save all the information I need in my database

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
process.setMaxListeners(0)

const BASE_URL = "https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre";

const PAGES = 4;

async function scrapeData(url) {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  //await page.goto(url)

  for (let i = 0; i < PAGES; i++) {
    await page.goto(`${BASE_URL}${i === 0 ? "/" : `/?p=${i}`}`);
    await page.waitForTimeout(6 * 1000);
  }
  

  // Naviguer vers la page cible
 // await page.goto('https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre/');

  // Attendre que les éléments contenant les données des produits soient chargés sur la page
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__price');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__img');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__description');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__availability');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__brand');
  await page.waitForSelector('.element_artikel__sku');

  // Extraire les données des produits en utilisant une fonction de la page
  const productsData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const priceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__price');
    const imageElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__img');
    const titleElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__description');
    const stockElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__availability');
    const brandElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__brand');
    const referenceElements = document.querySelectorAll('.element_artikel__sku');

    const products = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < priceElements.length; i++) {
      const price = priceElements[i].textContent;
      const imageUrl = imageElements[i].getAttribute('src');
      const title = titleElements[i].textContent;
      const instock = stockElements[i].textContent;
      const brand = brandElements[i].textContent;
      const reference = referenceElements[i].textContent;

      products.push({ price, imageUrl, title, instock, brand, reference });
    }

    return products;
  });

  // Fermer le navigateur
  await browser.close();

  return productsData;
}


// Fonction pour enregistrer les données dans MongoDB
async function saveDataToMongoDB(data) {
  const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'; // Changez cette URL en fonction de votre configuration MongoDB
  const client = new MongoClient(uri);

  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connecté à MongoDB');

    const database = client.db('scraped_data');
    const collection = database.collection('testing');

    // Supprimer les données existantes dans la collection
    await collection.deleteMany({});

    // Insérer les données dans la collection
    await collection.insertMany(data);

    console.log('Données enregistrées avec succès dans MongoDB');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Une erreur est survenue lors de la connexion ou de l\'enregistrement dans MongoDB:', error);
  } finally {
    // Fermer la connexion MongoDB
    await client.close();
  }
}

// Appeler la fonction de scraping, enregistrer les données dans MongoDB et afficher les données des produits
scrapeData()
  .then((data) => {
    saveDataToMongoDB(data);
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((error) => console.error('Une erreur est survenue lors du scraping:', error));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried your code, it either brings me random number of elements between 7 and 60, out of the 200 it should return, so here is a re-write of your code, pay attention to notes in the `scrapeData` function

Code : [new result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aycsQ.jpg)

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");

let browser;
(async () => {

    async function scrapeData(url) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless : "new"});
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 30000 });
        await page.waitForSelector(".element_product_grid");

        // if there is a popup accept it 
        let cookie = await page.waitForSelector(".cmptxt_btn_yes");
        (!! cookie) ? await cookie.click() : null; 

        let pages = 0; // set page to zero if page doesn't exist        
        let selector = "a.element_sr2__page_link:last-of-type";
        if (!! await page.$(selector)) { // does this element exist?
            pages = await page.$eval(selector, el => el.textContent.trim()); // get last page number
            pages = +pages - 1; // 4 pages but -1 as you're on the first page.
        } 

        let productsData = [];
        for (let i = 0; i <= pages; i++) {

            if (i != 0) { // skip page 1
                await page.goto(`${url}?p=${i}`, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 30000 });
                await page.waitForSelector(".element_product_grid");
            }

            // get the repeating part
            let products = await page.$$("a.element_artikel");

            for (let product of products) {
                // get data for each product
                const link = await product.evaluate(el => el.getAttribute('href'));
                const price = await product.$eval('.element_artikel__price', el => el.textContent.trim());
                const imageUrl = await product.$eval('.element_artikel__img', el => el.getAttribute("src"));
                const title = await product.$eval('.element_artikel__description', el => el.textContent.trim());
                const instock = await product.$eval('.element_artikel__availability', el => el.textContent.trim());
                const brand = await product.$eval('.element_artikel__brand', el => el.textContent.trim());
                const reference = await product.$eval('.element_artikel__sku', el => el.textContent.replace('Référence: ',''));

                productsData.push({ price, imageUrl, title, instock, brand, reference, link });
            }            
        }

        await browser.close();
        return productsData;
    }


    async function saveDataToMongoDB(data) {
        const uri = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'; // Changez cette URL en fonction de votre configuration MongoDB
        const client = new MongoClient(uri);

        try {
            await client.connect();
            console.log('Connecté à MongoDB');

            const database = client.db('scraped_data');
            const collection = database.collection('testing');

            // Supprimer les données existantes dans la collection
            await collection.deleteMany({});

            // Insérer les données dans la collection
            await collection.insertMany(data);

            console.log('Données enregistrées avec succès dans MongoDB');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Une erreur est survenue lors de la connexion ou de l\'enregistrement dans MongoDB:', error);
        } finally {
            // Fermer la connexion MongoDB
            await client.close();
        }
    }

    async function getLinks(url) {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: "new" });
        const page = await browser.newPage();

        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 30000 });
        await page.waitForSelector("header");

        // get links
        let links = await page.$$eval("a.sb_dn_flyout_menu__link", el => el.map( x => {return {link : x.getAttribute('href'), keyword : x.textContent.trim()}}));
        // filter links
        let filterArr = ["/haut-moteur/"]; // you need to manually write all sections you need to this array eg. look at the links on the site e.g. /pot-d-echappement/..        
        links = links.filter(x => {return filterArr.some(el => x.link.includes(el))});
        return links;
    }


    let urls = await getLinks("https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/"); //get all relative links

    let allResults = []; 
    for (let url of urls) { // process the links
        let result = await scrapeData(url.link);
        allResults.push(result);
    }

    allResults = allResults.flat(); // flatten array

    console.log(allResults);
    console.log(allResults.length);

    await saveDataToMongoDB(allResults);

})().catch(err => console.error(err));
```

note: the above takes some time getting the products, 5694 in total for `/haut-moteur/`

Comment: Thanks!
And I have a question, to optimize the thing it wouldn't be better to make it look for everything I need by "keyword", instead of going by category (https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/category/)

Because I want to do this for several sites, and the final goal will be that one script = one site

Comment: @SiriusB_ you can get all the links from the menu on the top using  ` let links = await page.$$eval("li > ul > li > a.sb_dn_flyout_menu__link", el => el.map (x => {return {link : x.getAttribute('href'), keyword : x.textContent.trim()}}));`  then send those to the `scrapeData` function, if by one site you mean everything under `https://www.maxiscoot.com`

Comment: Yes for https://www.maxiscoot.com, but I only want the engine parts, so: Cylinder kit, ignition, crankshaft...
Not everything that exists on the entire site

Comment: to filter the links the easiest way would be to make a filter array looking at the main sections in the menu ex. `let filterArr = ['/haut-moteur/','/bas-moteur/']; links = links.filter(x => {return filterArr.some(el => x.link.includes(el))});`  will only get links and keywords that are under `/heut-moteur/` and `/bas-moteur/`..

Comment: And when there are no other pages, what should I do? @idchi

Comment: @SiriusB_  updated the code in the answer to include getting pages, and data from them. I'm assuming you mean if there is a single page only by 'no other pages' I also added a check for that to the scrapeData function

Comment: Yes, if there is only one page. Except it doesn't work. 
and the edit of your code just loops on https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moto/?p=X)

Comment: @SiriusB_ edited version is for pages like [this](https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/cyclo/haut-moteur/accessoires-haut-moteur/)  or [this](https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-cross/haut-moteur/joint-cylindre/) where there is a single page and there is content in it, since you're getting existing links on the site you shouldn't run into a 404 page.

Comment: the edit version I use it for [this](https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/) Like what you have already marked in the code. (https://imgur.com/G6h6jPe)

Comment: @SiriusB_  before the `console.log(allResults);`  add `allResults = allResults.flat();` seems I didn't copy it over when pasting the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are giving your function too much responsibility at the moment by keeping track of the URL. I would move this out of the function and save the base URL in a variable to prevent duplication:

```js
const BASE_URL =
  "https://www.maxiscoot.com/fr/moto-50cc/haut-moteur/kit-cylindre";

const PAGES = 4;

async function scrapeData(url) {
  // await page.goto(url)
}

for (let i = 0; i < PAGES; i++) {
  await scrapeData(`${BASE_URL}${i === 0 ? "/" : `/?p=${i}`}`);
}
```

Comment: Can you help me reform my code? (With your addition (help))

Comment: You can update your question with your attempt and provide some info on what you need help with specifically